# IOS insert line break to data retrieved from parse.com

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, parse-platform

i am trying to retrieve some string data from parse.com and i've added "\n, \n & \r" into the data, but it still does not give me the line breaks, how do format the line below to get line breaks.

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"ParseStringDate"]];
```

Comment: are you sure that `[object objectForKey:@"ParseStringDate"]` returns multiline text?

Comment: yes it does @viperking

Comment: did numberOfLines worked for you?

Comment: its set to 0 through the editor,

Comment: this is how it returns the text **A girl \n story about a girl who brings hope to a broken family**

Comment: could you post all the code's fragments that modifies this label?

Comment: i actually found the solution, but stack overflow wont let me post the answer

Comment: what is the answer? you might have too low reputation

Comment: NSString *getString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"String"]];
                    NSString *myNewLineStr = @"\n";
                    NSString *myString = [getString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:myNewLineStr];

Comment: so in fact you where getting **A girl \\n story about a girl who brings hope to a broken family** not A girl \n story about a girl who brings hope to a broken family, that makes a difference!

Comment: its still a \n, but when the code comes through app, it converts it to \\n

Comment: so it is obvious why it was not working, so the problem is not with setting the label but with handling with data, please be more specific next time :) also posting an answer would be nice thing to do

Answer (score 1):

if you get the text that should be presented in multiple lines then you should try to set for your label this property:

```
self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

it basically means that label can be multiline, make sure that frame of that label is sufficient to show more that one line of text

Answer (score 1):

if some has the same challenge in swift - please find attached a short string extension:

```
extension String {
    func formatStringFromParseWithLineBreaks() -> String {
        let sourceString: String = self
        let resultString = sourceString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString: "\n")

        return resultString
    }
}
```

It is easy to use:

```
let stringFromParse = "Great\\nExample"
let newString = stringFromParse.formatStringFromParseWithLineBreaks()
```

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"first\n%@\n another", [object objectForKey:@"ParseStringDate"]];
```

Make sure you have `numberOfLines` of the label set to 0. This should work.

Comment: ive set the lines to zero through the interface, but it still shows the text with \n

Comment: Increase the height and width of the label in xib file. May be it hides the text.